# How can I create a condition that return something of the other function in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a game of ticking in C, so I should just change the checkStatus function. I'll show you the part of the code I'm having trouble with:

```
int checkStatus(char board[][3]) {

    int status = -1;
    **int j, i;
    if (board = ([][][],[][][],[][][]));
    return check Status(tab0);**

    return status;
}

int main(){

    char tab0[][3] = {{' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' '}};

    char tab1[][3] = {{'X','X','X'},{'O','O',' '},{' ',' ',' '}};

    char tab2[][3] = {{'O','X','X'},{'X','O','O'},{' ',' ','O'}};

    char tab3[][3] = {{'O','X','X'},{'X','O','O'},{'O','X','X'} };

    char tab4[][3] = {{' ',' ',' '},{'X','O','X'},{' ',' ',' '}};


    printf("Calculated Status: %i\n", checkStatus(tab0));

    printf("Expected status for board0: 0\n\n");

return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the bold part is what I tried to do, but it doesn't run (I'm new to this). What I want to do is a condition like:

"If the board has no 'X' or '0', the status must return the number 0 (according to the main function). I want to do it without putting printf in the "verificaStatus" function.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. And you can't compare arrays with `==` in C, it converts the array to a pointer and compares that.

Comment: What should `checkStatus` return if the board **does** contain an X or an O?

Comment: Why is `checkStatus` calling itself recursively?

Comment: It never sets `status` to anything other than `-1`.

Comment: `board = ([][][],[][][],[][][])` what is it?

Comment: Should return the 0 of the main function if there is nothing in the arrays, is the condition

Comment: Shouldn't `checkStatus()` take two arguments? The current board and the tab that you want to compare with?

Comment: *if there is nothing in the arrays* Do you mean is it contains only spaces?

Comment: I don't know how to call the " printf("Expected status for board0: 0\n\n"); " when the arrays are empty, do u know? @0___________

Comment: If there is nothing in the arrays, it should return 0, as the main function... @fpiette 
I am new in C, really don't know how to do that

Comment: *if there is nothing in the arrays* it is *nothing*  that I want you to define. There is no such concept in C language. You array contains *char* and there is no character named *nothing* so define it. My best guess is a space character. Or we could say * doesn't contain any 'O' nor 'X'*.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <string.h>

int checkStatus(char (*board)[3][3]) 
{
    int status = -1;

    if(!memchr(board, '0', sizeof(*board)) && 
       !memchr(board, 'X', sizeof(*board))) status = 0;

    return status;
}
```

Comment: This works! But the function is not calling the  "" printf("Status calculado: %i\n", verificaStatus(tab0)); "" Of the main funcion
I'm still very grateful